# SQL Server enters single user mode after cmd installation

Tags: sql, cmd, sql-server-2017

I am installing SQL Server Express 2017 using the command line. Once the install is done I use a batch file to create a database. The database creation fails giving a message that : login with 'sa' failed, The server is in single user mode

I have used the installation syntax given on the msdn website and my DB creation script is a batch file which creates a DB after confirming that SQL 2017 is installed. I am logging the errors in a file which gives me the single mode error information. Below is the installation statement I am using through cmd

```
SETUP.exe /q /ACTION=Install /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SAPWD=<Password> /SECURITYMODE=SQL
```

The code to install the DB is :

```
%OSQLEXE% -S %SERVER% -U %USERNAME% -P %PASSWORD% -i "%AgentPath%\CreateDatabase.sql" >> c:\InstallLog.txt
```

Ideally my DB should be created but for some reason I get this error. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to multi user mode and then creating DB as SA?

Comment: I’m not sure how I would do it in the batch file. All I could find is how to change to multi user mode from sql studio.

Comment: Its been a while.  I think you stop service, do ```SET MULTI_USER GO``` from prompt where connection is, and then restart service.  Or perhaps issue the command first and then restart service.